# How to automate querying AWS Accounts across all accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

we have an AWS organization with 50+ accounts and I would like to run some monitoring and auditing check across all accounts.

As I'm not too familiar with AWS CLI, is there a simple and complete guide somewhere showing the basic structure of a script that authenticates across all accounts ? I have seen some scripts in the internet, but they seem all somewhat insecure as they store the secret keys on a hidden folder, which is not ideal, is it ? I do the same in our Azure cloud and there we can securely hide this.

Would appreciate any leads, thanks!

Comment: Do you have an IAM Role in each account that can be assumed by a single set of credentials in a 'central' account? (Preferably, with that IAM Role having the same name.)

Comment: Also be aware of AWS Control Tower.

Comment: Yes, I have an account that has the sufficient permissions on all accounts. Just, I'm not sure how that would happen... would be great if I could see an example of how it's done using CLI or Powershell.